# Evaluate the limit $\lim _{x\to e}\left(\frac{1-\log _e\left(x\right)}{x-e}\right)$ without l'Hôpital's Rule

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

> $\lim _{x\to e}\left(\frac{1-\log _e\left(x\right)}{x-e}\right)$

I have tried to use this fact: $\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\left(a^x-1\right)}{a}\right)\:=\:\ln a$.

Comment: There is a typo in your "fact".

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** Identify the expression in the limit as the difference quotient of a particular function $f$ at a particular point $x_0$, and hence as the value $f'(x_0)$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to e}\dfrac{1-\ln x}{x-e}=-\dfrac1e\cdot\lim_{x\to e}\dfrac{\ln\left(1+\dfrac{x-e}e\right)}{\dfrac{x-e}e}=?$$ as $1=\ln e$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x):= \log_e(x)$. Then:

$\frac{1-\log _e(x)}{x-e}= -\frac{f(x)-f(e)}{x-e} \to -f'(e)$.

We have not used Lopitals rule, we only used the definition of the derivative.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\lim _{x\to e}\frac{1-\log _e(x)}{x-e}&= -\lim _{x\to e}\frac{\log_{e}(x)-1 }{x-e} \\
&= -\frac{d}{dx}\Bigg\vert_{x=e} \log_e(x) \\
&= -\frac{1}{e}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: The downvotes are usually a mystery for me, but the upvotes reach the unfathomable..

Comment: @RafaBudría  Understanding Mathematics may be difficult, but understanding the market can be impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try a different approach actually not related to L'Hôpital rule.

Suppose the limit $L$ exists, then calculate $e^L$

$$e^L=\lim _{x\to e}\exp\left(\frac{1-\ln x}{x-e}\right)=$$

$$=\lim _{x\to e}\exp(1-\ln x)^{1/(x-e)}=\lim _{x\to e}\left(\dfrac{e}{x}\right)^{1/(x-e)}=$$

$$=\lim _{x\to e}\left(1+\dfrac{e}{x}-1\right)^{1/(x-e)}=\lim _{x\to e}\left(1+\dfrac{e-x}{x}\right)^{(-1/x)(x/(e-x))}=$$

$$=\lim _{x\to e}\left[\left(1+\dfrac{e-x}{x}\right)^{x/(e-x)}\right]^{-1/x}=$$

$$=e^{-1/e}$$

Then $L=\ln e^L=\ln e^{-1/e}=-1/e$

Answer (score 1):

With the change of variable $x=e^{t+1}$,

$$\lim_{x\to e}\frac{1-\ln x}{x-e}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{-t}{e^{t+1}-e}=-\frac1e\lim_{t\to0}\frac{t}{e^{t}-1}=-\frac1e\frac1{\lim_{t\to0}\dfrac{e^{t}-1}t}.$$

Then use the given fact with $a=e$.